# PHP process capped at 30-33% CPU on windows

Tags: php, windows, windows-10, php-7, magento2.1

My php command line process can only run at 30-33% when running magento setup:di:compile no matter using nts or ts version.
My friend's Linux and MacOS php process can run 90%. With the same laptop spec (i5 2.6Ghz), they are able to finish magento setup:di:compile within 56seconds-1 minute while i finish in 3 minutes.
Also their magento run 3 times faster than my Windows.

[image]

I turn off xdebug already.
Is there any way to increase the cpu usage for PHP?

Comment: your environment under virtual or physical machine?

Comment: physical machine